# Nhibernate two transaction read the same table and insert the same table make one transaction fail

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, nhibernate

User Table structure
Id
Username (unique constrain)

I have the problem with Nhibernate and SqlServer like this.
There are two concurrent transactions trying to insert data in the User Table.
Both transactions query the data in table to check if the new Username to insert does not appear in the table.
The problem is that let say.
Transaction1 and Transaction2 read User Table and found that there is no username embarus in User Table.
Then Transaction2 trying to insert embarus in User table while Transaction1 has been inserted and committed embarus in  table already.

Therefore Transaction2 get exception for unique constrain.

Please help me to solve this problem, any ideas or article that may be useful.

I found that SqlServer 2008 uses ReadCommitted for default transaction isolation level.

Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. The DBMS is doing its job by flagging this issue for you to handle in your code. I think we need more information to be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to catch and handle the unique constraint violation. The best way to do that is to create an ISqlExceptionConverter implementation to translate the RDBMS specific exception to a custom exception in your application.

```
public class SqlServerExceptionConverter : ISQLExceptionConverter
{
    public Exception Convert(AdoExceptionContextInfo adoExceptionContextInfo)
    {
        var sqlException = adoExceptionContextInfo.SqlException as SqlException;
        if (sqlException != null)
        {
            // 2601 is unique key, 2627 is unique index; same thing: 
            // http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/26/sql-server-difference-between-unique-index-vs-unique-constraint/
            if (sqlException.Number == 2601 || sqlException.Number == 2627)
            {
                return new UniqueKeyException(sqlException.Message, sqlException);
            }
        }
        return adoExceptionContextInfo.SqlException;
    }
}

public class UniqueKeyException : Exception
{
    public UniqueKeyException(string message, Exception innerException)
        : base(message, innerException)
    { }
}
```

Usage:

```
            using (var txn = _session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    var user= new User
                        {
                            Name = "embarus"
                        };
                    _session.Save(user);
                    txn.Commit();
                }
                catch (UniqueKeyException)
                {
                    txn.Rollback();
                    var msg = string.Format("A user named '{0}' already exists, please enter a different name or cancel.", "embarus");
                    // Do something useful
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (txn.IsActive)
                    {
                        txn.Rollback();
                    }
                    throw;
                }
            }
```

Note that you should not reuse the session after the exception occurs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your good answer. However, for this solution, I need to insert username one by one. Do you have any solution that I can do batch insert.( insert multiple Usernames in the same time.

Thanks

Comment: I imagine your batch insert would loop through the users to be created and call a method containing code similar to my answer that inserts the usernames one by one. Actually inserting them in a batch (single transaction) would probably be a bad approach because the transaction would roll back all the inserts if one fails.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think you answer is the best solution.